# Why the enum parameter can NOT accept the int value(>0) in overload method

Tags: c#, enums

This is my code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public enum SexEnum{
        Male,
        Female
    }

    public static void Test(SexEnum s){
        Console.WriteLine("enum...");
    }


    public  static void Test(Object s){
        Console.WriteLine("object...");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(0);
        Test(1);
    }
}
```

But the actual result are:

```
enum...  
object...
```

Why the enum parameter can NOT accept the int value(>0) in overload method?

Comment: For extra amusement, try adding an overload that accepts an `int`. This behavior is all fully documented, but demonstrates the perils of overloading.

Comment: Only the value 0 has an implicit conversion to enum.  If you want this to be predictably then you need an overload that takes an *int* argument, apply a (SexEnum) cast.  Or just don't use int at all, the value ought to be converted in the caller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is clearly specified in the language specification, section 6.1.3 Implicit enumeration conversions (emphasis mine):

> **An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal
>   0 to be converted to any enum-type** and to any nullable-type whose
>   underlying type is an enum-type. In the latter case the conversion is
>   evaluated by converting to the underlying enum-type and wrapping the
>   result

So only the literal `0` can be implicitly converted to any enum, not `1`, not `2`, only `0`.

This can be further demonstrated by removing the overload that takes an `Object`, `Test(1)` will become unable to compile.

As to why the language is *designed this way*, you'll have to ask the language designers.