# Passing 0 to an overloaded function where one overload takes a enum, and the other a double, is ambiguous

Tags: c#, enums, overloading

I have an overloaded function. One of the functions takes a `double`. The other a named enum `MyEnum`.

If I call this function with 0, it throws compile time exception

```
Compilation error (line 8, col 3): The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.Foo(double)' and 'Program.Foo(MyEnum)';
```

Code to reproduce:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo(1); // No ambiguity 
        Foo(0); // Ambiguity
    }
    
    public static void Foo(double value)
    {
    }
    
    public static void Foo(MyEnum value)
    {
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/uR0d0F

Why does it not resolve to the double overload? I understand that all enums can be the value `0`. I am guessing that to the compiler, `MyEnum.A` and `0` are indistinguishable.

I am creating an API. Is this issue avoidable using generics or some other change to the function, that won't change what consumers have to do to call the function?

-- EDIT --
Solved by adding:

```
public static void Foo(int value)
{
    Foo((double)value);
}
```

Comment: The reason for your error is described here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56255321/19500804

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the enum parameter can NOT accept the int value(>0) in overload method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255125/why-the-enum-parameter-can-not-accept-the-int-value0-in-overload-method)

Comment: If you are creating an API, I'd say that the responsibility of resolving this ambiguity lies on the user. Whoever uses this can simply pass `0.0` instead.

Comment: My actual overloads were nullable doubles and enums (I didn't think this was relevant, strangely enough it is).
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/PVf1NT

Passing 0.0 in this case will not resolve this issue.
Assigning 0 (or 0.0) to an intermediate non-const variable, then passing the variable, does solve the issue. And that is currently the approach I am taking.

However, people calling the API will get very confused if they ever call it with a const 0 (or 0.0). This is rather unfourtunate. But it looks like this is just how the language has been designed.

Comment: @Sweeper This helps answer the question but not fully. That answer says that because `0` is implicitly convertible to an enum, it is ambiguous. However int is implicitly convertible to double, and it doesn't have this issue.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/q1s4So

Comment: What do you mean by "However int is implicitly convertible to double, and it doesn't have this issue"? What issue are you talking about? The fact that this is ambiguous is exactly because `int` is implicitly convertible to `double`. And yes, nullable does matter here because it makes the parameters "not exact matches", and that makes the overload less preferable. This is all explained in the [better function member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12643-better-function-member) section of the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type of `0` is `int`, it can be implicitly converted to `double` or any `Enum` type, which leads to ambiguity. To disambiguate between the methods without changing the call site, you need to accurately define an overload method as:

```
public static void Foo(int value)
{
    Foo((double)value);
}
```

Comment: Then how come this issue does not occur when there is an int AND double overload considering that int is implicitly convertible to double: dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/q1s4So

Comment: `Foo(1)` will call `Foo(int)` and `Foo(0.0)` will call `Foo(double)`, they are perfectly matched.

Comment: Ok that makes sense and your code does solve this particular case. 

However my real code actually takes `double?` and `enum?` (and already has `int?`). I didn't think this was relevant but turns out it is.

This example is not solved by your solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/QgRKld

And I don't understand why `0` is ambiguous when nullables are involved.

Comment: My solution takes an `int`, if you've already defined `Foo(int?)`, you can still define `Foo(int)`. Also, you should ask your actual questions.

Comment: I asked what I thought was the minimum reproducible problem. Considering that my MRP raises the exact same exception as my real code, for the same inputs. I think I can be forgiven for thinking it was the same question.

Comment: Because `0` is an `int`, it's convertible to any type of `double?`, `enum?` and `int?`, and the compiler cannot decide which conversion to use. But once you have `Foo(int)`, the compiler will know it's perfect because there's no conversion needed.